# How is PATH set for users in puppet?

Tags: environment-variables, path, puppet

I'm having an interesting [problem](http://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/13176/puppet-master-could-not-retrieve-fact-fqdnipaddress/) which I was able to work around by manually specifying `PATH`.

The problem is that although my `root` user's `PATH` is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

When I run my Puppet Master in NGINX/Passenger as user `puppet`, `PATH` somehow gets set to:

```
/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Where is the `PATH` environment variable set for users and how can I make sure that my `puppet` user has the right `PATH`? The user doesn't have a shell:

```
puppet:x:103:106::/var/lib/puppet:/bin/false
```

In my `config.ru` Rack file which is responsible for starting the Puppet Master, I've inserted the following statement to see what `PATH` the `puppet` user is running with:

```
puts "PATH: " + ENV.fetch('PATH', 'null')
```

The output is `PATH: null`, therefore the `PATH` environment variable is simply not set when Passenger is run.

I'm working in a Docker container running Ubuntu 14.04 amd64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it states [in the NGINX documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env):

> By default, nginx removes all environment variables inherited from its parent process except the TZ variable.

The workaround to my specific problem can be achieved in a few different ways.

#### Workaround 1: Append the PATH variable in Ruby

By editing the `config.ru` file, we can simply define `PATH` if it isn't already defined:

```
if not ENV['PATH']
    ENV['PATH'] = "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
end
```

This is simple enough and solves the problem, but is buried in configuration you'll probably never look at again.

---

#### Workaround 2: Set the PATH variable in NGINX

By setting the `PATH` variable in your NGINX site configuration, we have a more "immediately-visible" solution to the problem:

```
server {
    listen 8140 ssl default_server;

    # ...
    # manually set PATH for Passenger; see PUP-3000
    env PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    passenger_enabled on;
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general linux sets the `PATH` environment variable by reading the dot files. When you login, `/etc/profile` is read. After setting default environment variables it reads `.shell_profile` which is for example `.bash_profile`. If this dot file does not exist then it tries to read `.bash_login` and if that doesn't exist either, it will look for `.profile`.

Let's get back to the question. User `puppet` has no shell or does not accommodate the above mentioned files. You can simply check it by executing `echo "$SHELL" && echo "$PATH"`.

You eather can set `PATH` manually using one of the dot files or look at the following: http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/set-global-exec-path.html

Comment: Correct, user `puppet` doesn't have a shell. If the user doesn't have a shell, how can I override this? I've updated my question with an output of `cat /etc/passwd | grep puppet`

Comment: Also added some more debugging information to the question regarding Passenger.

Comment: You can either provide a shell (bash,zsh,ksh) to user puppet and then set `PATH` variable accordingly in the `.bash_profile` or you can tweak `sudoers` file.  Also see the following:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells